# How to inject resource and use it in the constructor

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, retrofit, roboguice

I would like to inject resource and use it in the constructor of singleton class with roboguice injection. Below is an example that shows what I need but injected field is null in the constructor. I was reading something about providers and overthink another special class for getting url but I am not so sure if it's convenient solution. Code below:

```
@Singleton
public class ProductService implements IProductService {

    @InjectResource(R.string.server_url)
    private String serverBaseUrl;

    IProductAPI productAPI;

    public ProductService() {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(serverBaseUrl)
                .build();
        productAPI = restAdapter.create(IProductAPI.class);
    }

    public ProductDTO retrieveProductByEan(String productEan) throws RetrofitError {
        return productAPI.getProductByEan(productEan);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see reading the Roboguice documentation, Roboguice framework is only thought for Android programming. See the following [link](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki).

Injections are done when the **super.onCreate()** method is called in an Activity.

Here is a portion of code of a full example in [github](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/blob/master/astroboy/src/main/java/org/roboguice/astroboy/activity/AstroboyMasterConsole.java):

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // @Inject, @InjectResource, and @InjectExtra injection happens during super.onCreate()

        sayText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

                // Have the remoteControl tell Astroboy to say something
                remoteControl.say(textView.getText().toString());
                textView.setText(null);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

So I recommend to use a static value to refer **serverBaseUrl**.